# ionic 3 disable all hardware buttons prevent from exit app

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

What I need to do is to disable the hardware buttons of Android (using **Ionic 3**), in order to prevent the app to close, or go back to Android main page, or exit the app in any ways.

I want to disable the **back**, the **home**, the **right** button and if it is possible the **button which closes** the device. Is it possible?

First of all I can't find the official documentation of Ionic "Platform" with its options and secondly I want to achieve the above.

Any help or instructions, it will be appreciated.

Comment: I really hope it's not possible. What use case is there for this?

Comment: Is for a registration form (a device for the public in a store). I don't want the people close the application or go to android menu in any ways.

Comment: Makes sense. Should be doable with Cordova kiosk mode plugin.

Comment: Let me check it and if it is working, I will take your answer as correct!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Kiosk mode https://developer.android.com/work/dpc/dedicated-devices.

Cordova has a Kiosk mode plugin as well https://github.com/hkalina/cordova-plugin-kiosk.

Comment: Failed to fetch plugin https://github.com/hkalina/cordova-plugin-kiosk.git via registry.
Probably this is either a connection problem, or plugin spec is incorrect.
Check your connection and plugin name/version/URL.

Comment: `cordova plugin add https://github.com/hkalina/cordova-plugin-kiosk.git` works for me.

Comment: That is strange. Which Ionic version you use?

Comment: Ionic CLI : 5.2.3, Cordova 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)

Comment: How to install this. Perhaps I am doing something wrong. Is there any other official plugin for Ionic 3?